# Date Range from now Query

Tags: mysql

I am creating a query to show performances 1 week before and 1 day after the current datetime, however I think maybe I'm missing a trick as it is either filtering the result one way or the other but not taking both parts of the range into account

```
SELECT BookID, concat(c.FirstName, ' ', c.SurName) as CustName, m.Title, pic.City, s.Name, DATE_FORMAT(p.TimeStarts, '%a - %b %e - %Y') AS Date, DATE_FORMAT(p.TimeStarts, '%h:%i %p') AS Time, b.NumAdults, b.NumChilds, b.TotalCost 
FROM booking b
JOIN customer c ON b.CustID = c.CustID
JOIN perf p ON b.PerfID = p.PerfID
JOIN movie m ON p.MovieID = m.MovieID
JOIN screens s ON p.ScreenID = s.ScreenID
JOIN pictures pic ON s.PictureID = pic.PictureID
WHERE b.BookID = BookingID AND p.TimeStarts > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND p.TimeStarts < NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY;
```

Any help on this matter would be very much appreciated

EDIT:
The Below Seems to have solved my problem, I have added or deducted the date and compared it to the current time, seems a little bit of a topsy turvy logic but oddly works...credit to Arth particularly in picking up on me doing the dates the wrong way round, will mark your answer as solved as it did help a great deal. A huge thanks to everyone else for their contribution

```
SELECT BookID, concat(c.FirstName, ' ', c.SurName) as CustName, m.Title, pic.City, s.Name, DATE_FORMAT(p.TimeStarts, '%a - %b %e - %Y') AS Date, DATE_FORMAT(p.TimeStarts, '%h:%i %p') AS Time, b.NumAdults, b.NumChilds, b.TotalCost 
FROM booking b
JOIN customer c ON b.CustID = c.CustID
JOIN perf p ON b.PerfID = p.PerfID
JOIN movie m ON p.MovieID = m.MovieID
JOIN screens s ON p.ScreenID = s.ScreenID
JOIN pictures pic ON s.PictureID = pic.PictureID
WHERE b.BookID = booking AND
(
p.TimeStarts - INTERVAL 6 DAY <= NOW()
AND
p.TimeStarts + INTERVAL 1 DAY >= NOW()
)
```

Comment: Consider ignoring all the other stuff for now. Just show us the perf table, and a desired result.

Comment: I would have done this initially, however I am wanting to filter the bookings using the said perf...The idea is not to show a performance earlier than a week of its start time and a 1 day after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query covers the range from 1 day before to 1 week after:

```
 p.TimeStarts > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND p.TimeStarts < NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY;
```

The range from 1 week before to 1 day after (as requested in the qu) is:

```
 p.TimeStarts > NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND p.TimeStarts < NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

I tend to use `>=` for the first operator as it works better for date based queries and I like the consistency. Unless this query is very time critical however, it will have negligible effect.

**UPDATE**

Personally I never use `BETWEEN` for date or time ranges, as more often than not I want the max to be exclusive.

Consider I want to include all bookings for 16th Nov, this is correct:

```
p.TimeStarts >= '2015-11-16' AND p.TimeStarts < '2015-11-16' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

This is incorrect as it includes 17th Nov at `00:00:00`:

```
p.TimeStarts BETWEEN '2015-11-16' AND '2015-11-16' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

I see this a lot, but it depends on second being the shortest time unit recorded and let's face it is pretty hideous:

```
p.TimeStarts BETWEEN '2015-11-16 00:00:00' AND '2015-11-16 23:59:59'
```

Comment: "expr BETWEEN min AND max" is equivalent to the expression (min <= expr AND expr <= max) if all the arguments are of the same type. BUt the same time, "BETWEEN" shows clearer intent and reads better (something SQL set out to do).

Comment: @malyy See update as to why I don't recommend `BETWEEN` and to be honest, unless you know it's inclusive, it ISN'T clearer because it isn't obvious. `>`, `>`, `>=` and `<` are much more transparent.

Comment: I have marked your answer as solved, see my main post if curious as to how I got around it

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use OR instead of AND

```
WHERE b.BookID = BookingID 
AND (p.TimeStarts > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY OR p.TimeStarts < NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

Comment: Hmm Im pretty sure I need both conditions not one or the other

Comment: @Albertoe86:- Not sure if I followed it correctly. But by using AND I dont think that both the condition can be met simultaneously. did you executed this?

Comment: Yes Just tried it, Have a date out of range and it has not been filtered out

Comment: @Albertoe86:- try this: `WHERE b.BookID = BookingID 
    AND (p.TimeStarts > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND p.TimeStarts < NOW())
    AND (p.TimeStarts > NOW() AND p.TimeStarts < NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY);`

Comment: Thats worked the other way round where its filtered out but also when its within the range

Answer (score 1):

> I am creating a query to show performances 1 week before and 1 day
>   after the current datetime

Your query should have date as

```
select * from table between `lowerdate` and `upperdate`
```

try this condition:

```
AND p.TimeStarts BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: Using CURDATE is completely different logic from using NOW.. are you sure this is what OP wants?

Comment: indeed, I just missed that it is needed to have datetime, but not date. As you previously noticed `CURDATE()` will give current date while `NOW()` will give full date time. 

Or, in other words =) :
`NOW() = CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', CURTIME())`